# Run msgbox when items are gone

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of shapes, which can be deleted.
However if at least one of them is deleted, then I am getting an error, that the object under the specified name wasn't found.

Basically I would like to make a comment after all, informing me, that all of the shapes have been already deleted.

My code looks like this so far:

```
 Sub Civremov()
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Tobyshape").Delete
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Toby").Delete
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Upturnshape").Delete
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Upturndesc").Delete
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Duct1").Delete
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Duct2").Delete

 End Sub
```

Now, when I attempt to delete these elements again, the errors says, that the object under a specified name wasn't found.
I would like to make a textbox like this:

```
     Msgbox("You have already deleted all civil features").
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch an error, however personally I usually like to loop over shapes, check their properties (name in your case) and act accordingly. You could opt to delete shapes when their name is found in a certain array of names?

For example:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName")
Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("Tobyshape", "Toby", "Upturnshape", "Upturndesc", "Duct1", "Duct2")

For Each shp In ws.Shapes
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(shp.Name, arr, 0)) Then
        shp.Delete
    End If
Next

Msgbox "All relevant shapes are deleted." 'Optional

End Sub
```

If we are speaking of a certain type of shape, you could also include that check into your `For` loop to minimize the times we call `Application.Match`